# Parse all inputs from UI into Single Json Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, python-2.7, api

I created a code (took help) which picks value from all the slider and drop downs.
I want to parse this as one single json object, lets say "data", how can i do this?
xyz is actually the container which has all the sliders and dropdown, I want to parse all the inputs from UI as single json object

```
  <script>
     $(function() {$('#analysis').bind('click', function() {
       $.post('http://127.0.0.1:5002/',{
         'CK': $('CK').val(),
         'OCE': $('OCE').val(),
         'SR': $('SR').val(),
         'ETP': $('ETP').val(),
         'CC': $('CC').val(),
         'RCD': $('RCD').val(),
         'range_01': $('range_01').val(),
         'range_02': $('range_02').val(),
         'range_03': $('range_03').val(),
         'range_04': $('range_04').val(),
       },
       function(data) {
                     var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
//i dont think this is correct- i want to just get data as json object.//
$("#xyz").text(parsed['abc']);
                 });
                return false;
         });
       });
    </script>
```

Image of inputs [image]

Comment: Ok. So what is not working?

Comment: //i dont think this is correct- i want to just get data as json object.//
$("#xyz").text(parsed['abc']);

This part- I am not sure what is happening in this part of code- will it give the final json object and I dont want to convert that into text

Comment: It depends on the returned object and what you're trying to do. `text()` method does not convert objects or any other types into text, it just appends some text to a given selector.

Comment: so what would be the output of this code::
xyz= (a json object contains all the 10 parameters from picture shown)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to the solution https://jsfiddle.net/um9h4L4t/

```
submit = function() {
    var child = $('#xyz').children();
    var data = {};

    for(var i=0; i<child.length; i++) {
        data[$(child[i]).attr('id')] = $('#' + $(child[i]).attr('id') + ' :selected').val();
    }

    console.log(data);
}
```

If you are looking for the same, not sure.

Comment: but its not posting to 'http://127.0.0.1:5002/'  also i am very new to jquery- I like your code but my problem is to post this data as 1 json object which i dont see.

Comment: Have a look to the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/um9h4L4t/1/ . You can refer to the document https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Currently in the fiddle example, POST API is failing because of the URL non -existing. Try in your local and let me know.

Comment: its says "method not allowed for this url " :( weird

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your code. Mostly js code.